# Package fails because System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near 's'

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, csv, ssis

My package was perfectly fine for couple of days and today whenever I tried to run it, it transferred few columns from the first file in the folder and failed.

The error that I'm getting is:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near 's'.
>
> Unclosed quotation mark after the character string
>   '','C:\Users\svojnovic\Dropbox\test\2016-08-31 Race 3 Scale Sheet.csv')'.

My code in the script task is:

```
SqlConnection myADONETConnection = new SqlConnection();
myADONETConnection = (SqlConnection)(Dts.Connections["DBConn"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction) as SqlConnection);

// Writing Data of File Into Table
int counter = 0;
string line;
// MessageBox.Show(fileName);

System.IO.StreamReader SourceFile = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileName);

while ((line = SourceFile.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if (counter > 0)
    {
         string query = "Insert into " + TableName + " Values ('";
         query += line.Replace(FileDelimiter, "','") + "','" + fileName.Replace(SourceFolderPath,"") + "')";

         MessageBox.Show(query.ToString());

         SqlCommand myCommand1 = new SqlCommand(query, myADONETConnection);
         myCommand1.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }

     counter++;
 }

 SourceFile.Close();

 // move the file to archive folder after adding datetime to it
 File.Move(fileName, ArchiveFolder + "\\" + (fileName.Replace(SourceFolderPath, "")).Replace(FileExtension, "") + "_" + datetime + FileExtension);
 Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
```

Comment: The error is telling you that your SQL code has incorrect syntax.  So you're going to want to look at your SQL code.  What is the runtime value of `query`?

Comment: One or other of `TableName`, `FileDelimiter` or `SourceFolderPath` presumably contains a single quote. use parameterised queries. You won''t be able to parameterise `TableName`  but the other values in the insert statement should be parameters. You should read up on SQL injection

Comment: I suggest having a read of the documentation on [SqlCommand.Parameters Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.8). Fix the injection issue, and the problem you're having goes away.

Comment: Why using  a script task?

Answer (score 0):

### Why importing flat file in Script Task??

The question can be asked in a different way: **What is the benefit of using SSIS if you are importing the flat file in a script task rather than Data Flow Task?**

You can simply add a Data Flow Task and use a Flat File Source and an OLEDB Destination to import data from a Flat File into an SQL Table. And on the other hand this will eliminate the SQL injection risk caused by concatenating the SQL command.

- [SQL SERVER – Import CSV File into Database Table Using SSIS](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/05/12/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-database-table-using-ssis/)

---

### Other methods

**(1) SQL BULK INSERT**

- [SQL Server insert from flat file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29019624/sql-server-insert-from-flat-file)

**(2) SQL OPENROWSET**

- [How to import data from .txt file to populate a table in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55366866/how-to-import-data-from-txt-file-to-populate-a-table-in-sql-server/55366960#55366960)
- [Import error using Openrowset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41883658/import-error-using-openrowset/41945440#41945440)

**(3) C# parameterized query**

- [c# import data from text file into sql databse line by line](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3ce5bb2e-85e9-4116-af6e-3d9c37111282/c-import-data-from-text-file-into-sql-databse-line-by-line?forum=csharpgeneral)
- [Loading Flat Files into a Database with C#](https://www.dwconsultants.com/loading-flat-files-into-a-database-with-c/)

---

### Helpful post

- [What's the most efficient way to load a csv file into SQL Server 2016?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/145089/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-load-a-csv-file-into-sql-server-2016)